# How is rate-limit in Azure API Management calculated

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management , rate and quota limit both have a renewal-period configuration.
For eg. 
renewal-period is defined as "The time period in seconds after which the quota resets."

My question is, when does the quota start , does it start from the first second of lets say 0000 GMT or is calculated from first request or is a rolling window.

Apigee has a very documentation of quota rate counters as documented [here](https://docs.apigee.com/api-services/reference/quota-policy)

Can someone explain how azure calculates it ?

Comment: rquota config example <quota calls="10000" bandwidth="40000" renewal-period="3600" />

Comment: question title should have been how is renewal-period calculated in rate limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rate limiting is using sliding window. Quota is using fixed window. We will update the documentation - thanks for the feedback!